# fiilna() method on Pandas ignores inplace argument returns error when called on axis=1

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am experimenting with the fillna() method. I have created a small dataframe and two Series for that purpose:

```
   col1    col2    col3      col4
0  NaN      NaN    3           4
1  NaN      NaN    7           8
2  9.0     10.0    11         12

n1 = pd.Series([10, 20])
n2 = pd.Series([30, 40, 50, 60])
n2.index = list(df.columns.values)
```

When I try the command:

```
df.fillna(n1, axis=0, inplace = True)
```

Nothing happens, the NaNs remain intact. I would expect to see them replaced with the values 10 (col1) and 20 (col2). When I try

```
df.fillna(n2, axis =1)
```

I get an error message:

> ```
> NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column
> ```

Could you explain this behavior? Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to specify the column for which you will fill in the values. For example,

```
df['col1'].fillna(n1, inplace=True)

df
Out[17]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0    10   NaN     3     4
1    20   NaN     7     8
2     9    10    11    12
```

---

In the instance that you are filling in a single value instead, say 0, you can apply it to the DataFrame as you did above. Starting with the original DataFrame,

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

df
Out[27]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     0     3     4
1     0     0     7     8
2     9    10    11    12
```

Answer (score 2):

The default axis for `fillna` is `0`.  This translates to matching the columns with the index of the series being passed.  That means that filling in with `n2` should be on `axis=0`

```
df.fillna(n2)  # axis=0 is default

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  30.0  40.0     3     4
1  30.0  40.0     7     8
2   9.0  10.0    11    12
```

Doing this `inplace=True` definitely works

```
df.fillna(n2, inplace=True)
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  30.0  40.0     3     4
1  30.0  40.0     7     8
2   9.0  10.0    11    12
```

---

```
df.fillna(n1, axis=1)

NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column
```

Yeah!  You're out of luck... sort of

***option 1***
`transpose()`

```
df.T.fillna(n1).T

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  10.0  10.0   3.0   4.0
1  20.0  20.0   7.0   8.0
2   9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0
```

***option 2***
use awkward `pandas` broadcasting

```
n1_ = pd.DataFrame([n1], index=df.columns).T
df.fillna(n1_)
```

Or `inplace`

```
df.fillna(n1_, inplace=True)
df

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  10.0  10.0     3     4
1  20.0  20.0     7     8
2   9.0  10.0    11    12
```